# Am I asking questions wrong, or do people just expect questions to be top professional quality?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, quality-improvement

I have asked a total of 15-20 questions, and half of them got downvoted, and I constantly get comments saying, "You need to fix your code" or "Make the question format better". I am in school, so I quickly make the questions.

I have read [How do I ask a Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and it says to describe the issue, and the details within a few sentences, and post code afterwards. I do that, yet people still downvote my posts, or leave comments that are irrelevant to the question, or just tell me to improve the question format.

A yellow box appears every time I ask a question, stating that I am at risk of being blocked for asking questions. I looked at the post that was linked about how to get unblocked once blocked from asking questions, and it states to edit current questions, and deleting questions gives me negative reputation. So I only deleted one question before I knew that; I never deleted a question again.

Do people expect questions to be made at a professional level, or I am just simply doing something wrong?

One of my questions: [remove the text from my brand on my navbar at a certain breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78009579/how-to-remove-brand-text-at-certain-breakpoint)

Comment: *"Quickly making the questions"* is probably part of the problem. **Take time and care** in creating your questions and ensure they are properly formatted, clear and understandable.

Comment: @yivi Thank you for pointing that out. Ive changed the question to a different question that is a programming question regarding html css and bootstrap.

Comment: On the currently linked question, why did you accept the answer when, as you say yourself, "This does not seem to work."?

Comment: Yeah, your new example **is** about a programming task, but it's rather poor (sorry if I sound harsh, I'm trying to give you feedback as it is, so you. understand the situation).. You just throw all your HTML + all your CSS and provide a task. You need to work a bit harder to provide a **minimum** reproducible example.

Comment: @yivi You mean like add a video of me reproducing the problem? I can surely start doing that if need be.

Comment: What? No, no! What gave you that idea?

Comment: "Reproducibility" means that someone else can copy your code and "reproduce" the problem. E.g. verify that the problem that you describe happens. It's not related to video in any way.

Comment: @Lil_PhyziX Did you actually read the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) help page that you were linked to? Because it looks like you took none of that into account, and interpreting the request as "add a video of me reproducing the problem" goes directly counter to the advice.

Comment: @Lil_PhyziX think of it this way, you have a project in which you have a problem in one part of it. You post about the problem on Stack Overflow but instead of removing all the noise and presenting only your problem you share your entire code. Does that make sense? You need to create an example that reproduces your problem with minimal amount of code. There's multiple questions out there on Stack Overflow and if you keep sharing code that doesn't focus on just the problem not only is this wasting other's time its reducing your chances of getting an answer as well.

Comment: it shouldn't take 1000+ lines of css to demonstrate your css issue.

Comment: @yivi alright. I normally just post all of the code, because my css is scattered all over the place, so i figured i post the entire css and turn it into a code snippet so it can be ran.

Comment: [The goal](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of Stack Overflow is to "_build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming._". Answers to questions here are not just for you, but to anyone else that faces the same problem in the future. So yes, we do expect questions to be top quality. Imagine being a busy programmer that tries to understand your question (either to answer it, or to use the answers). Would you like to go through 1000+ lines of CSS (most of it being irrelevant to the problem)?

Comment: @Ivar I never really realized that this is what people feel like when i just post all of my css. Thank you for the feedback! ill be sure to take this into account from now on when i make questions.

Comment: I'm generally a pretty busy person, but it typically takes me at least 45 minutes to an hour to write questions. If you're spending less than, for example, 20 minutes writing your question, it almost certainly has quality issues. You should also spend at *least* that long searching for duplicates (especially since 3 out of your 10 undeleted questions have been marked as duplicates, which seems like a somewhat high ratio to me to be honest). If you find similar posts, you should preemptively explain why your post is different.

Comment: "_ill be sure to take this into account from now on when i make questions._" => Yeah, but not only _from now on_, but also for your existing Questions...! The one you linked to will otherwise probably quickly gather Downvotes if you don't improve it...

Comment: Not that I'm biased, but I have a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52953756/unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection-an-existing-connection-was) in which I do that: there were lots of Q&A about a similar error message, but the error message I was asking about had a key difference that made the solutions to those not apply to my situation. I make the difference clear in the post, which helped prevent people from getting confused and downvoting or voting to close. It also helped people understand the question better so that I was able to get a good answer.

Comment: The real beauty of the minimal reproducible example (MRE), and the main reason many of us ask for them, is MRE is a distillation of divide and conquer debugging techniques and is a powerful way for you to find the answer to most questions without having to ask the question. As you hack off code building the MRE, the mistake has less room to hide and eventually the code becomes nothing but the mistake. You may not know WHY it is a mistake, and that's a great time to search Stack Overflow for an answer and should that fail, ask a question. Make the MRE early and you're usually done early.

Comment: I will foot stomp the need for an appropriately sized MRE. However, important to point out we are not a help desk, so the fact you are a student in school or have decades of experience as programmer, really does not change the criteria of what makes a good question. At the end of the day, your inexperience is a problem, you must overcome with an appropriate amount of understanding necessary to ask the question you require us to answer. You are not expected to be a expert, but we do expect you, to have enough understanding of the problem and topic to provide a MRE that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @user4581301 Wish I could upvote that more times. Yet it's fascinating how much lip I've gotten over the time from even "experienced" people when asking for a better MCVE (or MRE in the newspeak). Even just asking for some more detail, as if that was such a weird thing to do when you're trying to solve a problem...

Comment: It is unhelpful & unclear to ask 'A or B' when A & B are not mutually exclusive and/or not the only options. (And you may think they are when they are not.)

Comment: "I am in school, so I quickly make the questions." This is irrelevant & not a reason to post bad questions & a reason to not post questions.

Comment: Alright, well i dont mean to be rude, or pointing figers or whoever may call it, but this is just my opinion. i dont really believe that this whole reputation system should be the key to blocking users from posting, or giving them a bad name. my reputation has been setting a very bad name for me, only because i don't spend an hour - 2 hours making a question? I could be using that time to be solving another problem. I understand that people do help with their own time, but i should be able to include minimal details, and be able to have others understand it, so i can get back working on things

Comment: This is not a helpdesk though as has already been said, it is a knowledge base. Closer to a wikipedia than to a Reddit. You end up here if you never took the time to understand what Stack Overflow is. People are not helping *you*... they are committing answers that help *everyone* with the same problem. The only way that works is if the question is good to begin with. Not something that is hastily outsourced "because schoolwork".

Comment: Note: Reputation means extremely little or nothing to the server when deciding when you can ask questions. Whet gets you banned is questions that were not upvoted. Score of 0 is bad. The logic is if a user predominantly asks questions that the community does not deem to be useful contributions to the Q&A library, the server cuts off that user to reduce the noise they are adding to the library.